# fstream I/O not reading/writing

Tags: c++, io, polymorphism, fstream

I am getting no output from this code, possibly due to an infinite loop (don't take my word for it, though). I followed my book very closely, to no avail.

I get no errors but nothing happens when I run.

The program needs to open a file, change it's contents character by character and write them to a different file (this is an abridged version).

```
class FileFilter
{
protected: 
ofstream newFile;
ifstream myFile;
char ch;

public: 
void doFilter(ifstream &myFile, ostream &newFile)
{
while (ch!= EOF)
{
myFile.get(ch);
this->transform(ch);
newFile.put(ch);

virtual char transform (char)
{
return 'x';
}
};

class Upper : public FileFilter
{
public: 
char transform(char ch)
{
ch = toupper(ch);
return ch;
}

};


int main()
{
ifstream myFile;
ofstream newFile;

myFile.open("test.txt");
newFile.open("new.txt");

Upper u;

FileFilter *f1 = &u;

if (myFile.is_open())
{
while (!nyFile.eof())
{
f1->doFilter(myFile, newFile);
}
}
else
{
cout << "warning";
}
myFile.close();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are also missing a couple of braces in the FileFilter class.

Comment: I'm wondering why you need the while loop outside of the filter function as you have the while loop inside the filter function or vice versa.

Comment: Should also close new file, and you don't need to use this-> to call transform. But all of this is incidental. There isn't anything that I can see that is wrong.

Comment: The extra loop you mentioned above is the only thing I can think of as well.  And yeah, those are all just typos. Is there really nothing else wrong? That 's so odd considering that it's not working properly. @DominicMcDonnell

Comment: closing or not closing a file can sometimes make a difference (operating system dependent), try newFile.close(); at the end. That said, it's highly unlikely.

Comment: `transform` should take a reference.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier to help if you posted compilable code. :)

You're right in that there's an infinite loop, here:

```
void doFilter(ifstream &myFile, ostream &newFile)
{
  while (ch != EOF)   // <--- ch will never equal EOF
  {
    myFile.get(ch);   // <--- this overload of get() only sets the EOF bit on the stream
    this->transform(ch);
    newFile.put(ch);
  }
}
```

because the stream's `get()` method does not set the character to EOF at end-of-file. You can use the parameter-less version to get that behaviour: `ch = myFile.get();`

Otherwise, you should be testing for `!myFile.eof()` like you do in main().

---

Also, you're not actually using the transformed value of `ch` so this code won't change the value in the output file. Either make transform() work with a reference so it alters its parameter, or do `ch = this->transform(ch);`.